# How to use AutoIt with Maven project?

Tags: maven, autoit

i'm getting exception when instantiate autoit with maven project
noteL that with java project (with build path) there is not exception!

```
String jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
engine = new AutoItX();
```

My Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: m_pDispatch
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:101)
at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
at autoitx4java.AutoItX.<init>(AutoItX.java:231)
at utils.AutoIt.init(AutoIt.java:28)
at utils.AutoIt.<init>(AutoIt.java:17)
at utils.AutoIt.getInstance(AutoIt.java:33)
at utils.AutoIt.engine(AutoIt.java:39)
at utils.AutoItAPI.run(AutoItAPI.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Compatibility issues between jacob or autoITDLL. I have resolved this issue using version 1.16 of jacob dll. It's working fine for me.